# Intuitively, why doesn't a ball retract to a sphere?

Tags: general-topology, spheres, retraction

I'm a studying an intro to topology course and we have just learnt about retractions. As a side note, the lecture notes state that the ball $\mathbb{B}^{n}$ does not retract to $S^{n-1}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (due to *Brouwer*).

*Definition*: A subset $A\subset X$ is a *retract* of $X$ if there is a map $r:X\to A$ such that the restriction satisfies $r|_{A}=\text{Id}_{A}$, $r$ is known is the *retraction*.

Suppose we had the function $$r(x) = \frac{x}{\|x\|}$$ for all $x$ except the origin, then a ball without the origin would map to the sphere. Can we not just then map the origin to some random point on the sphere? What's wrong with my understanding?

Comment: I think a retraction must be continuous?

Comment: Thank you, this is what I assumed.

Comment: @JoshuaFarrell, if you consider that map $r$ and you extend it to the whole ball by stipulating that the origin is sent to a fixed point $p$ of the sphere, then observe that, _for every_ $\epsilon >0$, there are points in the open ball $B(origin, \epsilon)$ that $r$ sends to the "opposite direction" w.r.t. $p$. That's why your extended map will never be continuous.

Comment: Thats fantastic thank you @GennaroPasquale

Comment: @GennaroPasquale Write your comment as an answer, it is the perfect intuition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning of the word "map" is context dependent.

If by "map" we understand plain function then retracts are not interesting: in this sense **any** subset of **any** set is a retract of that set. And your solution is one possibility.

But in the context you are dealing with, the word "map" means "continuous function" (and we know, or at least assume that, because you've mentioned Brouwer, spheres, balls, i.e. topological context). And note that your newly constructed function **is not** continuous, regardless of the choice of $r(0)$. Why? Hint: take any point $v\in S^{n-1}$, $v\neq r(0)$ and consider the sequence $r\big(\frac{1}{n}v\big)$.

Also there are other interesting worlds with retracts, e.g. algebraic structures and homomorphisms. In fact the concept of ["retraction"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_(category_theory)) can be defined for any [category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_(mathematics)).